# Child Class Needs a Child of Parent's Member Variable

Tags: java, oop

I have a Parent View class that contains a Parent Model.  This parent model MUST be defined in the parent view.  Also, each child view has its own corresponding extension of that parent model.  I can assign the child model to the parent model in the child class, but every time I want to use a method defined in the child model, I have to type-cast it.  How do I avoid this?  Could I permanently type cast?

Comment: This reminds me of [Parallel Inheritance Hierarchies](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/smells/parallel-inheritance-hierarchies).

Comment: Thank you so much!  I had no idea what it was called and it was a pain in the rear to search for on google!  That is exactly my problem!